# Android - adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged problem

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, clone

So I've an adapter which takes its data from an ArrayList And I'm trying to filter the ArrayList by a few parameters that the user chooses, but the adapter doesn't update, and even makes it look like the ArrayList is empty, Any Suggestion how to fix it?

Code Below:

```
if (task.isSuccessful())
   {
     updatelist(task.getResult(), dateStr, time);
     zoneAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

(Thats inside a OnCompleteListener)

updatelist:

```
zones.clear();
int count = 0;
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : result) {
       zoneid = document.get(AssignmentFirebase.ZoneId).toString();
       dateAssignment = document.get(AssignmentFirebase.date).toString();
       timeAssignment = document.get(AssignmentFirebase.TimeSlot).toString();
       if (timeAssignment.equals(time) && dateAssignment.equals(dateStr))
                {
                    for (int i =0; i< allZones.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (allZones.get(i).getId().equals(zoneid))
                            allZones.remove(i);
                    }
                    zones = (ArrayList) allZones.clone();
                }
```

The adapter is connected to the ***zones*** ArrayList
I've used a debugger to check it in detail, seems like it deletes the zones that needs to be deleted so its probably the clone or the adapter itself, i would appreciate any help, Cheers.

Comment: I think we need to see more code.  Where are you setting up your adapter?

Comment: ''' zones = new ArrayList<Zone>();  
        allZones = new ArrayList<Zone>(); 
        lstZone = findViewById(R.id.lstZone); 
        zoneAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, zones); 
        lstZone.setAdapter(zoneAdapter); '''                                                          
        that's onCreate